# Matlab: Extracting a ROI with center coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, roi

I have a mammographic image of size  1024 x 1024, and I have the center coordinates of the anomaly (338.314) and the radius (56) in pixels of the circle containing the anomaly. I desire to extract a region of interest of size 128 * 128 including the anomaly. I tried with

```
rect = [338-64,314-64,127,127]; 
crop = imcrop (img, rect) ;
```

but I obtien an ROI that does not contain the desired anomaly.
any suggestions please.

Comment: Are you sure the 'system of reference' is correct? In Matlab a pixel located at a coordinate (1,1) is at the top left corner, so maybe you need to change the coordinates in rect accordingly.

Comment: Adding to @Benoit_11 's answer, the `(x,y)` co-ordinate assumes the **column** location is `x` and the **row** location is `y`.  Also, the orientation of the image is `y`-down, meaning that positive values of `y` go down the `y`-axis, not up.

Comment: i think that the system of reference is correct, because this is a reference database, a lot of people work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's matrix indices are in `(row,column)` format, while rectangle's indices are usually in `(x,y)` format.
This means that you probably need to swap the two first elements of rectangle.

```
rect = [314-64,338-64,127,127]; 
crop = imcrop (img, rect) ;
```

Comment: @user3127771 - It has already been done.  As you can see, the row and column co-ordinates have been flipped in comparison to what you see in your post.